# Can't get UIScrollView to scroll on Swift Storyboards?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

[image]

Hey guys,

I'm trying to get a UIScrollView to work here but it doesn't really work? I can't scroll it.

Here's what I've had:
View
- Scroll View (set constraints to be 0,0,0,0 to View)
-- contentView (set contraints to be 0,0,0,0 to scroll view, equal widths and heights as contentView, priority 250)

but I still haven't been able to scroll it? I've seen all tutorials and followed them and there is nothing that can fix it. Is there a setting that I have been missing? Is there something I might have accidentally toggled? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It happens because scrollView doesn't know it's content size. Check if the top constraint of the top stack view is set and also the bottom constraint of the bottom stack is set. P.S. it also might happen because of nested stack views inside of the scroll view. In case constraint solution won't work, create another view and store all the stacks inside of it. So hierarchy would be: ScrollView > ContentView > Container View > Stack views.

Comment: @inokey Does that mean my scrollView should have a constant height and width?

Comment: `scrollView` itself in a typical fullscreen scenario has constant height and width because it's constraint to margins of the screen. Your content view should be of a _known_ size, but known doesn't mean constant. It means that all the views inside of a `contentView` must have proper constraints. Meanwhile all of the edges of `contentView` should be equal to the `scrollView`, and also `width` of the contentView should be equal to `scrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that you can tweak:

1. Go to Size Inspector of the View Controller (in your case - Edit Programmes View Controller), change the **Simulated Size** to **Freeform**.
2. Turn off the Content Layout Guides in the Size Inspector of the ScrollView
3. Add 0 Constraint to Top, Bottom, Leading, and Trailing
4. The contentView that is inside your ScrollView must have an equal Width with the ScrollView.
5. Then add Height Constraint according to the number that is already inside it.

I hope it can help.

Comment: Done all this and it still doens't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you set the frame of your UIScrollView so that it is less than the Content Size. Otherwise, it won't scroll.

Comment: Can you screen shot the complete Constaint Layout for me to check it again? I think you make some mistakes when doing it.

Comment: I have add some tweaks in it, let me know if it still cannot scroll.